# UITableView overriding UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I am implementing two navigation bars with a table view underneath both of the bars.  The only problem i am having right now is that whenever the view gets loaded, the table view gets displayed over the navigation bars.  I have scaled the uitableview in the interface builder to have the view show two navigation bars with a table view fitting below both.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: can you explain your question little more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not clear what you’re asking here. Are the navigation bars and table views side-by-side, or what? It’s worth noting that just setting the “Top Bar” property on a view in Interface Builder only sets the default size of the view—you’ll need to set up your navigation bar (or navigation controller) manually. That said, it’d help if you explained what you’re trying to accomplish with a dual-tableview/navigation-bar setup; it’s not a typical UI pattern on the iPhone, and on the iPad such things are usually implemented with a split-view controller.

Comment: sorry.  I have uploaded an image ([link](http://imgur.com/iiuR2)) that helps show what I am trying to display.  The view will be 2 navigations bars at the top, then the rest of the view will be the table view.  sorry for not being clear initially